# Problemas de seção crítica em programação concorrente

Tags: c++, thread

Estou implementando em C++ um sistema com threads usando semáforos. Estou com uma dúvida, se eu tratar a situação de progresso, vou garantir 100% que minha implementação não vai ocorrer nenhum impasse? Ou preciso ter cuidado com mais alguma coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que não ocorra nenhum impasse quando está se tratando de seção crítica, deve-se atentar além do `Progresso` a `Exclusão mútua e Espera Limitada`.

**Exclusão mútua** – Se o processo Pi estiver executando em sua seção crítica, então nenhum outro processo poderá estar executando em suas seções críticas.

**Progresso** – Se nenhum processo estiver executando em sua seção crítica e houver alguns processos que queiram entrar em sua seção crítica, então a seleção dos processos que entrarão na seção crítica em seguida não poderá ser adiada indefinidamente.

**Espera limitada** - É preciso haver um limite sobre o número de vezes que outros processos têm permissão para entrar em suas seções críticas depois que um processo tiver feito uma solicitação para entrar em sua seção crítica e antes que essa solicitação seja concedida:
Suponha que cada processo seja executado em uma velocidade diferente de zero
Nenhuma suposição referente à velocidade relativa dos N processos.

Caso esses três fatores ocorram, ocasionará em DeadLock. Para garantir que não ocorra DeadLock, basta garantir que um desses fatores nunca ocorra.